# Import video file into vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, html5-video

I have converted a m4v file type into a mp4 file type with [https://cloudconvert.com](https://cloudconvert.com/). Currently in my Visual Studio Code set up I have `assests/video/videoName.mp4`. When I click on the mp4 file I get a message saying *"The file is cannot be displayed in the editor because it is binary or uses unsupported text encoding"*. Any tips? I may be overlooking a small detail.

Comment: The editor is a **text** editor so here a video file is rejected because it is not a text document giving valid text (using A to Z alphabet). I don't use VSCode myself but from a quick [Google search](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=vscode+mp4+preview) I think the first link in those search results might help you.

Answer (score 0):

you need to download the MPEG-4 PREVIEW extension, and then it will open normally

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).